# При попытке передать информацию с помощью Transfer-Encoding: chunked, клиентская сторона читает данные обычным способом

Tags: c++, веб-программирование, http, веб-сервер, http-server

При отправке информации с помощью http-чанков посылаю клиенту вот такой набор заголовков:

```
 static const char hdr[]=
     "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n"
         "Transfer-Encoding: chunked\r\n"
     "Connection: keep-alive\r\n";
```

После этого добавляется заголовок с типом данных(Content-Type:) и закрывается двумя \r\n, за этим следуют сами чанки, которые формируются в этом методе:

```
std::string httpHandler::chunk_create(const std::string &block)
{
    std::ostringstream chank;
    chank << std::hex << block.length();
    return chank.str() + "CRLF" + block +"CRLF";
}
```

Проблема в том, что браузер не понимает, что я передаю информацию чанками, и вместо этого просто добавляет к html страничке размер файла и crlf(иными словами, не интерпритирует составленный чанк как чанк, а читает как информацию полученную без заголовка Transfer-Encoding: chunked).Если браузер не понимает, что информация передается чанками, то,я думаю, ошибка в заголовках.

Вопрос в том, где я ошибся? Может стоит добавить еще заголовоки или исправить существующие(пробовал отправлять с заголовком Vary: Accept-Encoding)? Как исправить возникшую проблему?

Comment: CR — это `\r`, LF — это `\n`, CRLF — это `\r\n` — вот это вот и надо слать, а не четыре английские буковки

Comment: Кроме того, chunked появился в HTTP/1.1, а у вас написано 1.0, поэтому клиент обязан игнорировать ваш chunked и читать данные обычным способом